# AngularJS Custom Filter duplicates

Tags: angularjs

I currently meet an issue with a custom filter. I have an array of CVE objects called 'cves' (in my scope), and for each item I generate a tr line in a table using ng-repeat.

Here is the global structure of a CVE:

```
cve: {
  id: integer,
  cve: string,
  summary: text,
  description: text,
  cvss:{
    score: float,
    vector: string
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<input type='text' ng-model='searchField'/>
       ....
       <tr ng-repeat="cve in cves | cveFilter:[ad_filters, searchField] as filtered_cves"
            ng-if="cves.length > 0">
            <td colspan="7" class="no-padding">
               //printing infos in a custom directive
            </td>
        </tr>
        ....
```

Here is my filter :

```
.filter('cveFilter', function () {
    return function (cves, params) {
        console.log(cves);
        let items = {
            ids: params[0],//the ids (array of ids)
            text: params[1],//the text
            filtered_cves: []//the output
        };
         // for each cve, if its ID is in items.ids
         // AND if one of the property of the CVE match with items.text
         // push it to items.filtered_cves


        cves.forEach(function (cve) {
            if (
                items.ids.includes(cve.id) &&
                (
                    cve.cve.match(items.text) ||
                    cve.summary.match(items.text) ||
                    cve.description.match(items.text) ||
                    cve.cvss.score.match(items.text) ||
                    cve.cvss.vector.match(items.text)
                )
            ) {
                items.filtered_cves.push(cve)
            }
        });

        return items.filtered_cves;
    };
});
```

My problem is the following : my filter seems to work, it keeps only the matching CVEs but it displays each CVE in duplicate. That means if I have 6 cves in my $scopes.cves array, i will have 12 lines in my html table.

It's my first custom filter but I think it's a stupid mistake.

Do you know where I failed ?

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, is it duplicating the data, or is it making a blank line aswell as your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is duplicating the data, I don't get blank lines.

If I print the content of $scope.filtered_cves, I get (let's say I am supposed to get 8) 16 elements.

I didn't mention that earlier, but $scope.ad_filters is an array of CVE IDs I want to display. A CVE is displayed only if its ID is in $scope.ad_filters AND if one of its property matches with the content of the input form text.

I can't screenshot at the moment, I need to put fake data.

Here is the updated code for my filter (nothing really changed, just added some functions) :

```
.filter('cveFilter', function () {
    return function (cves, params) {
        let items = {
            ids: params[0],
            text: params[1],
            filtered_cves: []
        };

        cves.forEach(function (cve) {
            console.log(cve);
            if (items.ids.includes(cve.id)) {
                if (items.text === '' || items.text === null || items.text === undefined ||
                    (
                        cve.cve.toString().includes(items.text) ||
                        cve.summary.toString().includes(items.text) ||
                        cve.description.toString().includes(items.text) ||
                        cve.cvss.score.toString().includes(items.text) ||
                        cve.cvss.vector.toString().includes(items.text)
                    )
                ) {
                    items.filtered_cves.push(cve)
                }
            }
        });
        return items.filtered_cves;
    };
});
```

I ran it and I noticed that it is executed several times, and the last time it prints twice too much lines.

Comment: This is solved. When I opened this topic I thought it was my filter but it turns out that by mistake I called twice the function that populate the datasource.